# VBA Skip blank does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I have this code in excel, which copies a range and pastes it. However it does not skip blanks, how it is supposed to do.

```
With Worksheets("Calculator")
    .Range("H10:H61").Copy
    Worksheets("Graphs").Range("D2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=True, Transpose:=False
End With
```

The range `H10:H61` contains only values, no fromulas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly, skip blanks doesn't do what you think it does, you can read here what it does [Chandoo](http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/03/19/skp-blank-cells/)

Try the code below instead:

```
Dim VisRng As Range

With Worksheets("Calculator")
    Set VisRng = .Range("H10:H61").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    VisRng.Copy
    Worksheets("Graphs").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlValues
End With
```

Comment: How can adapt the code so it works with cells with formulas, which give text results

Comment: @tombata change the last part `SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)`

Comment: I tried this, it copies the range, but it keeps the blank cells

Comment: @tombata if the cell has a formula, and the result is `""` it will stil copy it

Comment: Yes, this is the case. How can I work around this problem?

Comment: @tombata sounds like a new SO question, i think you should post this new question, add you latest working code, this will allow other users to answer your post as well (besides me)